# How can I download FFMpeg git? I keep getting permission denied error

Tags: raspbian, streaming-video, ffmpeg

I tried many ways to download FFMpeg but to no avail. http://jollejolles.com/installing-ffmpeg-with-h264-support-on-raspberry-pi/ 
I used this website as reference and I managed to do everything up to the point where I have to download FFMpeg but when I try to download it on my Raspberry Pi terminal, it keeps saying could not create work tree dir permission denied. How do I solve this?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly the issue is. How do you download FFMpeg? With `git clone`? Do you actually have permissions to do so?

Comment: What version of Raspbian do you use? Is it Buster?

Comment: Instead of downloading from git you can try a source archive from https://ffmpeg.org/download.html.